# Unable to Use Key Vault Reference for Azure Function App Environment AzureWebJobsStorage via CI/CD deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

I was hitting the error `Unable to find the storage account associated with the function app` upon a pipeline deployment today for an Azure Function App. I am using Azure DevOps with the following snippet to generate a Key Vault Reference from our pipeline deployment (using `AzureAppServiceSettings@1`):

```json
  {
  "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
  "value": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=${{ variables.KEY_VAULT_NAME }};SecretName=AZUREWEBJOBSSTORAGE)",
  "slotSetting": false
},
```

When this is set as the value for `AzureWebJobsStorage` though, I get the error from above.
I guess this is caused by Key Vault references not populating until the function app is initialized (run-time), whereas the check resulting in this error for the storage account occurs before.

After setting the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value to the resolved secret value inside Azure Portal, the error goes away.

Wondering:

1. Can we use a Key Vault reference for `AzureWebJobsStorage` through DevOps deployment (using the tasks `AzureFunctionApp@1` and `AzureAppServiceSettings@1` ?)
2. Which other values might not take effect or cause deployment issues when managed this way (using a Key Vault reference?) Is this behavior documented?

Comment: what is the error you are getting when you directly refer using the keyvault syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Its possible to add **`@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret)`** while value in the  **`AzureWebJobsStorage`** setting via **Azure DevOps pipeline** while deploying your Function App.

I have created one Key vault with RBAC as Access management, If you have Access Policies make sure you have given the Get, List, Set, Delete and other required Secret Permissions to the Function App managed Identity and The Azure DevOps service connection that you have used for the Function App deployment.

As **I have used Azure RBAC for Key vault**, I have assigned **Key vault Administrator to my Function App as well as my Azure DevOps service connection**:-

***Enabled Managed Identity for my Function App:-***

[image]

***Roles Assigned to access Key vault:-***

[image]

My Azure DevOps pipeline with App Settings:-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  # group: KeyVaultGrp
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxx08-aaxxx6469165e7'

  
  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc87'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'



  
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.6 as of today

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
              appType: 'functionAppLinux'
              appName: 'siliconfunc87'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              appSettings: '-AzureWebJobsStorage @Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=valleyKeyvault;SecretName=AzureWebJobsStorage)'
```

Make sure the setting is in the same format as below in your yaml pipeline script:-

```yaml
appSettings: '-AzureWebJobsStorage @Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=valleyKeyvault;SecretName=AzureWebJobsStorage)'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***The secret got retrieved and added successfully:-***

[image]

[image]

***Function got deployed and ran successfully:-***

[image]

*One more alternative ***is to connect your Key vault secret to your Variable Group and reference it directly in your yaml code***:-*

[image]

```yaml
variables:

group: KeyVaultGrp
.
.
.
.
.
appSettings: '-AzureWebJobsStorage $(AzureWebJobsStorage)'
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the detailed walkthrough. I'm wondering if maybe using `AzureAppServiceSettings@1` is what was causing the issue, rather than specifying the secret within the `AzureFunctionApp@1` app settings property... in any case, injection into the pipeline using Key Vault groups is another option. Appreciate it!