# Managed Identity is not supported for Function on Container App Environment

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to use bicep to build up an azure function in azure container apps environment. I would like to bind some user assigned managed identity to connect the function to cosmosdb.

After deploying function with bicep below:

```
resource azfunctionapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: functionName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,linux,container,azurecontainerapps'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${umi.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    name: functionName
    managedEnvironmentId:environment.id
    siteConfig: {
    linuxFxVersion: 'Docker|${image}'  
    appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: azStorageConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: appi.properties.ConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL'
          value: '${acrName}.azurecr.io'
        }
        {
          name: 'DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME'
          value: acrName
        }
        {
            name: 'DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD'
            value: acr.listCredentials().passwords[0].value
        }
      ]
    }
    
  }
}
```

I got error message like : `\"Message\": \"Managed Identity is not supported for Function on Container App Environment. object is not present in the request body.\"`

As the function in azure container apps is now in preview. Is this feature not supported now as the message shown. Or, did I made any mistake in the bicep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred this [MS Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-custom-container?tabs=core-tools,acr,azure-cli2,azure-cli&pivots=container-apps) [MS Document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-container-apps-hosting#functions-in-containers) and there's no mention of adding managed identity for functions in container app environment.

Also, Azure Container Apps is in Preview. Thus, in Preview service not all features are available but they are updated regularly by Microsoft.

As an alternative you can make use of CosmosDB Connection string and store its value in the keyvault and utilize the bicep file below:-

```
resource azfunctionapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: functionName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,linux,container,azurecontainerapps'
  properties: {
    name: functionName
    managedEnvironmentId: environment.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'Docker|${image}'  
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: azStorageConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: appi.properties.ConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL'
          value: '${acrName}.azurecr.io'
        }
        {
          name: 'DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME'
          value: acrName
        }
        {
          name: 'DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD'
          value: acr.listCredentials().passwords[0].value
        }
        {
          name: 'CosmosDBConnectionString'
          value: '@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<your-secret-uri-in-keyvault>)'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am also looking for some workarounds. I tried to use keyvault to config my settings, but without an identity configured, I am not sure what is the right way of connecting my azure function to Azure KeyVault.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, Refer this blog here- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/a-secure-way-to-use-credentials-and-secrets-in-azure-functions-7ec91813c807

Comment: Also, my SO answer where I haave referenced key vault settings to function app via azure devops pipeline - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77648990/unable-to-use-key-vault-reference-for-azure-function-app-environment-azurewebjob/77651343#77651343

Comment: Hi @SiddheshDesai, thanks for your response. But I still feel confuse to the solution. As the blogs mentioned, first of all, I should use a system-managed or user assigned managed identity which is related to the azure function, and then grant KV permissions to the identity. But, in this case, the function in Azure Container App env can not use any identity, I failed to bind any identity to the function actually.   So, I did not find a good way of accessing KV from my function and use the features provided by azure functions like in the common environment.

Comment: If this is the case, Provide a service principal access to your Function App in Container app and Key vault. then use that service principal as a user assigned managed identity to access your key vault from Function app with container

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try this solution and look forward to the official support from Azure Function team!